# Failed to get_identifier_token from HTC Desire HD with fastboot

Tags: fastboot

My HBoot is HBOOT-2.00.0027, I got the following problem when I was trying to unlock my HTC Desire HD following the instruction http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader

It seems HBOOT 1.0 has this problem and someone suggests to update HBOOT to 1.2, but my HBOOT is already 2.0, should I downside update to 1.2?

E:\HTC_G10\system_software\root_tools>fastboot oem get_identifier_token
...
(bootloader) [ERR] Command error !!!
OKAY [  0.016s]
finished. total time: 0.016s

```
E:\HTC_G10\system_software\root_tools>fastboot.exe /?
usage: fastboot [ <option> ] <command>

commands:
  update <filename>                        reflash device from update.zip
  flashall                                 flash boot + recovery + system
  flash <partition> [ <filename> ]         write a file to a flash partition
  erase <partition>                        erase a flash partition
  getvar <variable>                        display a bootloader variable
  boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]              download and boot kernel
  flash:raw boot <kernel> [ <ramdisk> ]    create bootimage and flash it
  devices                                  list all connected devices
  continue                                 continue with autoboot
  reboot                                   reboot device normally
  reboot-bootloader                        reboot device into bootloader

options:
  -w                                       erase userdata and cache
  -s <serial number>                       specify device serial number
  -p <product>                             specify product name
  -c <cmdline>                             override kernel commandline
  -i <vendor id>                           specify a custom USB vendor id
  -b <base_addr>                           specify a custom kernel base address
  -n <page size>                           specify the nand page size. default: 2048
```

Comment: HTCdev notes that the Desire HD requires an HBOOT upgrade to unlock. It looks like the most recent version is 2.00.0029.